# How to remove all repeating elements from a list in python?

Tags: python, list, element

I have a list like this:-

```
[1,2,3,4,3,5,3,6,7,8]
```

I want to remove the repeating element (here:- 3) completely from the list like this:-

```
[1,2,4,5,6,7,8]
```

How do I implement this in python such that not only the first occurrence of duplicate element is removed but all the duplicating values are removed

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from `collections` to count the number of occurrences and select those elements which appear exactly once using a list comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter
a = [1,2,3,4,3,5,3,6,7,8]
[k for k, v in Counter(a).items() if v == 1]
```

(`Counter` basically returns a dictionary where elements are stored as  keys and their counts are stored as values.)

Answer (score 1):

This code should work

```
#Finding duplicate
def dup(x):
    s = len(x)
    duplicate = []
    for i in range(s):
        k = i + 1
        for j in range(k, s):
            if x[i] == x[j] and x[i] not in duplicate:
                duplicate.append(x[i])
    return duplicate

#begining
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8]
#Finding duplicate
dup_list = (dup(list1))
#removing duplicates from the list
final_list = list(set(list1) - set(dup_list))
print(final_list)
```

Comment: Note that this is an extremely inefficient solution. *Each* of the `for` loops and possibly the `not in duplicate` check are O(n), reaching a time complexity of O(n^2) to O(n^3) in total – an optimal solution only needs O(n) time complexity and is no worse in space usage.

Answer (score 0):

Use a set. To get rid of all repeating values use this:

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,3,5,3,6,7,8]
print(a)
a = list(set(a))
print(a)
```

That will output

```
[1,2,3,4,3,5,3,6,7,8]
[1,2,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: No, this keeps the 3.

Comment: Setifying the list will give unique values. OP wants to completely remove duplicate entries.

Comment: Ohhhh I read it wrong. I thought you wanted all duplicates gone

Comment: Downvoting *because of Google* is hardly justifiable and even downvoting because of duplicates on Stackoverflow isn't really nice behavior - closing as duplicate is the proper way.  Plus, your code is incorrect AND doesn't output what you claim - I get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` which is in line with `set` behavior. -1

Answer (score 0):

A good and efficient way will be to use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
sample_list = [1,2,3,4,3,5,3,6,7,8]
unique_list = list(pd.Series(sample_list).drop_duplicates())

>> unique_list    
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```